# Rename files by reversing number order

Tags: shell-script, files, rename

I have a lot of files that are named like:

```
data1_1.txt
data1_2.txt
data1_3.txt
data2_1.txt
data2_2.txt
...
```

However these were downloaded and named in the reverse ordering. How could I rename all of these in a batch so that the result would be:

```
data1_3.txt
data1_2.txt
data1_1.txt
data2_2.txt
data2_1.txt
...
```

My first thought was just a bash / zsh script but if there's another tool that would work better please let me know.

Comment: I would write a "script that writes a script": write a script (in any language) that produces in its output the commands that you would need for the renaming *but does not execute them*. Then check the output carefully to make sure that it does exactly what you want. When you are sure you've got it right, save the output to a file, make it executable and then run it. Do not fall into the trap of e.g. in the case of three files named `one`,  `two` and `three`, doing `mv three one; mv two two; mv one three`, or you will live to regret it :-) And do it all on a copy of all the files.

Comment: Welcome! What is exactly "reverse ordering"? Can you give an example of the result you are aiming for?

Comment: do you have more than a single digit for each of the sequences (i.e. could there be a `data1_13.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc

typeset -A c=()
zmv -n '(*)_<->.txt(#qnOn)' '$1_$((++c[${(b)1}])).txt-renamed' &&
  : zmv '(*)-renamed' '$1'
```

(remove the `-n` (dry-run) and `:`, if happy (and remember to re-initialize `c=()` before running again without dry run)).

- `<->`: is like `<1-12>` to match decimal numbers in a range, but here with no bound specified, so matches any sequence of one or more decimal digits. Could also be written `[0-9]##` where `##` is `zsh`'s equivalent of ERE `+`.
- `(#q...)` is the *explicit* syntax for specifying [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).
- `n`: sorts numerically
- `On`: sorts by name in reverse. So with `n` above, that sorts the list of matching files numerically in reverse.
- For the replacement, `$1` contains what's captured in `(*)`, so the part before `_<digits>.txt`.
- We append `$((++c[${(b)1}]))`, where `$c` is the associative array declared earlier.
- `${(b)1}` is `$1` with glob characters escaped (without it, it wouldn't work properly if `$1` contained `]`).
- we do it in 2 stages (append a `-renamed` suffix which is stripped in the second stage), to avoid overwriting files in the process.

On your sample, that gives:

```
mv -- data2_2.txt data2_1.txt-renamed
mv -- data2_1.txt data2_2.txt-renamed
mv -- data1_3.txt data1_1.txt-renamed
mv -- data1_2.txt data1_2.txt-renamed
mv -- data1_1.txt data1_3.txt-renamed

mv -- data1_1.txt-renamed data1_1.txt
mv -- data1_2.txt-renamed data1_2.txt
mv -- data1_3.txt-renamed data1_3.txt
mv -- data2_1.txt-renamed data2_1.txt
mv -- data2_2.txt-renamed data2_2.txt
```

Note that technically, it doesn't *reverse the order*, or only does it in the case where the numbers are incrementing by one and start at 1 like in your sample. It will turn all of `[1, 2, 3]`, `[4, 5, 6]`, `[0, 10, 20]` to `[3, 2, 1]`.

To reverse the list, it would be a bit more involved. It could be something like:

```
all_files=(*_<->.txt(n))
prefixes=(${all_files%_*})

for prefix (${(u)prefixes}) {
  files=(${(M)all_files:#${prefix}_<->.txt})
  new_files=(${(Oa)^files}-renamed)
  for old new (${files:^new_files})
    echo mv -i -- $old $new-renamed
}
```

(remove `echo` when happy).

And run the `zmv '(*)-renamed' '$1'` again as the second phase.

On a different sample with a additional `[0, 3, 10, 20]` list as a third example, that gives:

```
mv -i -- data1_1.txt data1_3.txt-renamed
mv -i -- data1_2.txt data1_2.txt-renamed
mv -i -- data1_3.txt data1_1.txt-renamed
mv -i -- data2_1.txt data2_2.txt-renamed
mv -i -- data2_2.txt data2_1.txt-renamed
mv -i -- data3_0.txt data3_20.txt-renamed
mv -i -- data3_3.txt data3_10.txt-renamed
mv -i -- data3_10.txt data3_3.txt-renamed
mv -i -- data3_20.txt data3_0.txt-renamed
```

Those solutions make no assumption on what character (or non-character) the file names may contain, won't rename files unless they end in `_<digits>.txt`. The `zmv`-based approach will guard against overwriting files named with a `-renamed` suffix that would have been  there beforehand, not the latter approach (though `-i` will cause `mv` to prompt you before that happens). Alternatively, instead of adding a `-renamed` suffix, you could move the renamed file into a `renamed` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bash snippet to do the job assuming files are indeed named the way you've depicted them (`data<one-digit>_<digits>.txt`).

```
shopt -s extglob

#gather files into array
files=( data[[:digit:]]_+([[:digit:]]).txt )

#zip original files with their target file names and feed to mv
paste <(printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}" | sort -k1.5,1n -k2n -t'_') \
    <(printf '%s.ren\n' "${files[@]}" | sort -k1.5,1n -k2nr -t'_') | 
    xargs -n 2 mv --

#strip the temporary .ren suffix
for f in data*.ren; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.ren}"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

First, rename all files to prefix "old-":

```
for i in *
do
    mv "$i" "old-$i"
done
```

Then run this command and eyeball the output to make sure it looks good:

```
ls -v | tac | sort -s -t _ -k1,1 | sed -e 's/^old-//' | paste <(ls -v) - | sed -e 's/^/mv /'
```

If it does, pipe the output to sh.

Here's what's happening.

- `ls -v` produces them in sorted order (the -v says to sort 11 after 9, for example)
- tac reverses the whole input (the entire file; bear with me!)
- the sort says do a stable sort on only the characters before the first `_`.  The `-k1,1` **and** `-s` are both important to make sure you get the right output.  Without the -k1,1 the rest of the line is used to resolve duplicates, which we don't want, and without `-s` duplicates are ordered arbitrarily.

The rest is easy enough.

Comment: Cool solution. I had to add --color=never, because my colored ls output disturbed the command. Here is a final oneliner:
```for i in *; do mv "$i" "old-$i"; done; ls --color=never -v | tac | sort -s -t _ -k1,1 | sed -e 's/^old-//' | paste <(ls --color=never -v) - | sed -e 's/^/mv /' | bash```

Answer (score 0):

for a start you may try like this:

```
mkdir x
for base in $(ls data* | sed 's/_[0-9][0-9]*.txt//' | sort -u ) ;do
  ls ${base}_*| tac | for i in data1*; do
    read x;cp $i x/$x
  done
done
```

It works well only for special cases, you may have unexpected results with unpadded numbers like 1 2 11 111 or filenames like data1_somethingelse1.txt, not to mentions space or special characters in filenames.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution and I believe it would work for your situation very well. What we are doing here is, first checking how many file types we got by prefix. Here by file type prefix I meant data1_*, data2_* and so on. Then for each prefix type, we are then getting the total number of available files and storing them into an array called `totalFilesForEachPrefix`.

Then, in step 1 we are renaming the file to a temporary file. The reason for moving to `otemp` extension is to avoid name collision and overwrite the existing file. Here, I assumed that you have files like 1_1 1_2 1_3 1_4 and so forth.

Then, in step 2, we are just getting rid of `.otemp` extension.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
totalFileTypeByPrefix=$( for file in data*_1.txt; do echo $file; done | wc -l )
totalFilesForEachPrefix=()
for (( prefix = 1; prefix <= totalFileTypeByPrefix; prefix++ )); do
  totalFilesForEachPrefix+=( $( for file in data${prefix}_*.txt; do echo $file; done | wc -l) )
done
### Step 1
prefix=1; type=0;
while (( prefix <= totalFileTypeByPrefix )); do
  suffix=${totalFilesForEachPrefix[$type]}
  for file in data${prefix}_*.txt; do
    mv $file data${prefix}_${suffix}.txt.otemp; echo "$file renamed temporary --> data${prefix}_${suffix}.txt.otemp"
    suffix=$((suffix -1))
  done
  type=$((type+1))
  prefix=$((prefix+1))
done
### Step 2
echo "....Finally changing the temporary files"....
for tempfile in *.otemp; do
  file=${tempfile::-6};
  mv $tempfile $file; echo "$tempfile renamed final --> $file";
done
```

Here is the output with an explanation of whats happening:

```
data1_1.txt renamed temporary --> data1_3.txt.otemp
data1_2.txt renamed temporary --> data1_2.txt.otemp
data1_3.txt renamed temporary --> data1_1.txt.otemp
data2_1.txt renamed temporary --> data2_2.txt.otemp
data2_2.txt renamed temporary --> data2_1.txt.otemp
....Finally changing the temporary files....
data1_1.txt.otemp renamed final --> data1_1.txt
data1_2.txt.otemp renamed final --> data1_2.txt
data1_3.txt.otemp renamed final --> data1_3.txt
data2_1.txt.otemp renamed final --> data2_1.txt
data2_2.txt.otemp renamed final --> data2_2.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

A stupid, but always functional method (following [The KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)) is this:

```
/bin/ls data*.txt >rename.sh
# edit the file so that instead of
# data1_1.txt
# each line reads
# mv data1_1.txt data1_3.txt
# (you can use column selection in your editor)
sh rename.sh
```

Of course, it is obvious, but usually doing this is a way faster than fiddling with complicated (and one-of anyway) scripts.

(edited later) Comments are right, that in this case using this technique can lead to the loss of data (`data1_3.txt` can be wiped out). Therefore it is safe to make move in two steps: first change names, but move the file to some safe location (either add arbitrary false extension, or create a temporary subdirectory, where all files are moved), and then in the second step move all files to their final destination.

Comment: This is prone to fall into the trap I mentioned in my comment: you really have to be very careful to avoid trashing one or more of the files.

Comment: This would overwrite an existing file. More info at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/557157/rename-files-by-reversing-number-order/557253#comment1035109_557157